# pytest.mark.parametrize using values from global fixture

Tags: pytest

I have the following test function(under test_foo.py):

```
@pytest.mark.db
@pytest.mark.parametrize("ver", db_versions)
def test_create_db(ver,record_property):
        record_property("db_version", ver)
        ... and so on ...
```

and the global fixture to supply the values in my conftest.py:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "db_versions" in  metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.config.getoption("--dbver").split(",")
```

But when I try to call tests via:

```
python3 -m pytest --db --dbver 11,12,13
```

It will fails with:

```
    ???
E   NameError: name 'db_versions' is not defined
```

I also have tried it with:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")

```
def db_versions(pytestconfig):
...
```

But the result are the same.
Have some one an hint how to do this in a correct manner?
Thanks

Comment: The fixture name you want to check in `pytest_generate_tests` is "ver", not "db_versions".

Comment: I have tried to replace "db_versions" by "ver" in the pytest_generate_tests function, but the result is the same.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, so I can just guess what you want to do... Please show what `pytest_generate_tests` actually does, e.g. what it does with the option. Do you want to parametrize the test function? In this case you can't also do it manually.